# Cannot Drag View to Create IBOutlet

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

For some reason, I cannot ctrl+drag my view to viewcontroller.h to create an IBOutlet. Anyone have any ideas what I can do to get this working?

Please see screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM1LP.png

This is my viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SelectVideo1.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize littleView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yahoo.com"];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [littleView loadRequest:myRequest];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your web view and see whether if there is any connection given. sometimes it happens because u already have some connection and end up in giving again.